# Getting confused adding new pages to a Web App

Tags: .net, angular, model-view-controller

Basically the job has the API and Databases all set up in Visual Studio as a MVC project and I update and create new content in a separate Angular CLI project in VS Code and link to it (I think, I'm more a Front End Developer)

But where I am struggling to understand is where do I create new pages for the Site and how? Right now I've made a Folder with a newPage.component.html, newPage.component.scss and newPage.component.ts but they're not linked to anything yet

Is this the right way to do this? Or should I be making them in the API sections instead?

Comment: Are we talking about the Angular side of things here?

Comment: Yep, I edited the Angular made pages that already exist, so its still dealing with that side, I believe the API side is not really for me to touch outside of endpoints or I guess routing?

Comment: I think I can only advice you to go through an Angular tutorial. It is a fairly complex framework with a bit of a steep initial learning curve… but totally worth it! Go through the angular.io Tour of Heroes tut and things will become clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much correct.  The API should exist to give you the data you need on the front end.  So when you create a new component in Angular, you can fetch the data and display it.  You "link" your angular components (you called a folder) by using either your routing module ei: { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent} or you can use a component directly in the html by adding its selector  to wherever you want it displayed.

Comment: Ok, so I think I have a idea here, so right now its set up to where the API in Visual Studio runs the Backend/API and the VS Code folders are where the src is and the Frond End Pages are located (if that makes sense) so I should create these new pages here and link to the Visual Studio files via Routing in the component.module.ts file?

Comment: I agree with a comment above that you should go through a quick Angular tutorial.  Your API in visual studio is its own thing that would run on a server.  Your front end is an angular site, but you could be a mobile app or desktop app that could call the same api.  It just gives you data.  You should call the api (I am not sure link is the correct term here) from your component.ts files, the module file should list the components in that module.

Comment: Thanks, I will be doing that as well, you're right it is calling the API for a Mobile AND Desktop App

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an SPA your setup should be Asp.net core web api + Angular frontend. You dont need MVC, as the backend won't serve any views. Your api will serve only data, as rleffler pointed out. As for creating new pages, just use angular-cli to create new components. In fact, you use cli to generate almost everything in the frontend. If you are new to Angular, just read the heroes tutorial on the angular website and then some routing tutorial. I think routing is one of the first things one should learn when starting with Angular.

Comment: Yea I think I'm getting confused between the MVC backend and the Angular frontend, I am a Front End dev so really should only be working on the Angular side. I am reading through this Heroes tut again though